# Encode/Decode a EXE file into base64 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I think encoding is pretty simple, I have the script here:

```
import base64

fr = open("test.exe", 'rb')

while True:
    piece = fr.read(75232000)
    if not piece:
        break
    fw = open('testoutput.txt', 'wb')
    fw.write(base64.b64encode(piece))
    fw.close()
fr.close()
```

And for decode I have this:

```
import base64

decoded_string = base64.b64decode("string")
with open("testoutput1.exe", "w") as exe:
    exe.write(str(decoded_string))
```

But the result of the decoded file doesn't work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when saving your encoded version don't open the ".txt" in binary mode: it is a string representation.

Then just read the encoded file

```
ft = open('testoutput.txt', 'r')
encoded = ft.read()
```

And then write it to the final destination

```
with open("testoutput1.exe", "wb") as exe:
    exe.write(base64.b64decode(encoded))
```

Note: this time you must open the file for writing in binary mode (`"wb"`); and you don't want to convert the content to a string with `str()`.